# AWS API Gateway set up for Lambda Email Function Persistent 403 On Options Pre-fetch

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have been tearing my hair out trying to get API Gateway to be the front door and trigger for a Lambda function.

I set up a Lambda, called "ContactFormLambda" that accepts a POST, with the details:

```
{
  "subject": "Enquiry from ZenithWebFoundry",
  "name": "contact.name",
  "number": "contact.number",
  "email": "*******@gmail.com",
  "comment": "this is a test"
}
```

Now, in the API Gateway, I created a new API called "contact" and created a new rescource called "contactformlambda", set it up as a proxy to the lambda and defined a POST method (because that's all I'd be doing.

I tested this through the gateway and it works.

This is the API Gateway settings under the Lambda (from the above work):
[image]

I then wanted to be able to POST to the gateway from a form, so I realised that I'd need CORS, so I enabled CORS on the resource. This created an OPTIONS method with the three headers on it:

```
access-control-allow-headers
access-control-allow-methods
access-control-allow-origin
```

Then I tried to submit the form, but the options pre-fetch fails with a 403. I have followed the instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html) to do all of this. I have tried lots of variations and nothing seems to work.

Having said that, one of the times, it did work, but it let everything through not just the domains that I had specified in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin field. I can't see what I did differently here. It feels like each time I set it up, it does something different. I'm obviously inept at this, can anyone clear this up?

Answer (score 0):

I got this somewhere towards working. Basically, Ignore the "Enable CORS" Action from the Actions menu in API Gateway: it doesn't work, [instead follow this guide](https://enable-cors.org/server_awsapigateway.html).

Also, the persistent 403 for me was caused by the url to the resource being case sensitive. I was trying to hit:

https://ovo5xmxf7e.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/prod/ContactFormLambda

but the actual url was:

https://ovo5xmxf7e.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/prod/contactformlambda

crazy huh?

I said, "somewhere toward working", because basically CORS works a little too well. I specified:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 'http://zenithwebfoundry.com'

And despite this coming back in the POST response:

General

```
Request URL:https://ovo5xmxf7e.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/prod/contactformlambda
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 
Remote Address:54.230.243.227:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Response Headers

```
access-control-allow-headers:Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,x-requested-with
access-control-allow-methods:POST,OPTIONS
access-control-allow-origin:http://zenithwebfoundry.com
content-length:0
content-type:application/json
date:Mon, 12 Feb 2018 10:36:17 GMT
status:200
via:1.1 fda24eb25587b7e25d4fa1c50a862ba0.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id:b7DscV6b6qWl_mHUsEi77nRjICECZD3bd2iXiFv89A1d_xrDvfBQ0Q==
x-amzn-requestid:8d5578fc-0fe0-11e8-9e16-65a7dc0a72e4
x-amzn-trace-id:sampled=0;root=1-5a816e1f-aeeb63ef8590ed3868fe4149
x-cache:Miss from cloudfront
x-requested-with:*
```

Request Headers

```
:authority:ovo5xmxf7e.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com
:method:POST
:path:/prod/contactformlambda
:scheme:https
accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br
accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.9
cache-control:no-cache
content-length:147
content-type:text/plain
origin:http://localhost:4200
pragma:no-cache
referer:http://localhost:4200/contact
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36
```

It still completed the action even though my origin was clearly not http://zenithwebfoundry.com. So why is the

```
access-control-allow-origin:http://zenithwebfoundry.com
```

setting ignored?

Also, another observation, I have noticed that the pre-fetch is no longer happening. I have tracked it down to the fact that I am no longer sending any CORS disallowed headers (I was sending Access-Control-Allow-Origin in a mistaken belief that I had to send it in the request). I have now started sending "x-requested-with:*", which now forces the preflight check to see if "x-requested-with" is allowed to be sent.

I was hoping the pre-flight check would also prevent execution of the post from localhost, but it doesn't.